# GeoServer WFS does not find a point with mixed geometry

Tags: geoserver, geometry

I created a layer with mixed geometry. This layer contains ring and point geometry. When I click on the ring geometry, it returns object data, but if I click on the center point, there is no data. What can be done to make it work?

I tried to unite two layers into groups and try to do this, it worked. But according to business logic, I can’t do that.
[image]